# Does php mail has any limit (Number of mails per day) or php mail function

Tags: php, function, email

Does php mail has any limit (Number of mails per day) or php mail function limit depend upon the server configuration

Comment: entirely server dependent

Comment: Depends on hosting provider service

https://support.mailpoet.com/knowledgebase/lists-of-hosts-and-their-sending-limits/

Comment: Check your hosting provider knowledge base, they usually enforces such limits

Answer (score -1, accepted):

PHP does not have a limit.

To set a limit, you have to define a wrapper for the sendmail command in php.ini

```
 sendmail_path = /usr/local/bin/wrapper-to-sendmail
```

on a server basis. I do have such wrapper code, but I understand that this is not your question here.

You can also fix a quota per directory in the above script using the environment variable `PWD`.